# Using & when referencing relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, safe-navigation-operator

I am working through a tutorial book and I came across something I had never seen before.  In rails I am accustomed to getting the values of a relationship like this

```
<%= current_user.favorites.count %>
```

The author of the book used the `&` operator when doing this though, which appeared to do the same thing (I believe that I understand the `&` operator, I have just never seen it used like this)

```
<%= current_user&.favorites&.count %>
```

There was no explanation for this, so I took it as just another way to write it, but I have never seen this before in years of working with Rails and reading books/tutorials.

**Is there a performance reason for doing it like this**, or is it just personal preference?

It was inside a `turbo_frame_tag` if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is the safe navigation operator and prevents a NoMethodError if you call a method on `Nil`.

Its use here isn't really that strange - what you're calling an "association" is after really just a method generated what is presumably `has_many :favorites`. So here the author is calling the method no matter if the record exists or not and is then creating an extra db hit with a `COUNT` query. Not great.

Its all kind of silly too since you most like want to wrap it with some markup so you'll need an `if` anyways.

Using long chains of the safe navigation operator is regarded as an antipattern of sorts since it lets you violate the Law of Demeter with blatant disregard and masks bugs.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation on this I appreciate it.

Comment: I realize I may have misrepresented his code by removing something I thought was unnecessary to the point, the original was this, `<%= current_user&.favorites&.count || 0 %>`.  Thanks again for your reply

Comment: Thats actually funny. If its a like counter or something it makes no sense at all to display 0 if the user isn't even signed in. The safe navigation operator is one of those things that makes my spidey sense tingle as its one of the most misused language features.

Comment: @RockwellRice *" prevents a NoMethodError if you call a non-existant method method (such as calling a method on Nil)."*, should probably be reworded to *"returns `nil` if the receiver is `nil:NilClass`, which can prevent a NoMethodError when the initial object, or the return from a method call, is `nil`"* because the existence of a method, or lack thereof, has no impact on the safe navigation operator e.g. `1&.upcase #=> NoMethodError` and `nil&.to_i #=> nil`

Comment: @engineersmnky you're absolutely right.  Edited.